# QAF Flutter driver is trying to click on element that is not present and get's stuck there

Tags: qaf, flutterdriver

This is how element is defined

```
@FindBy(locator = "flutter-valuekey=xxx")
public FlutterElement btnPost;
```

And then I'm just doing

```
btnPost.click();
```

Following is the log from appium. I can see that there is an expeception.
[image: Appium Log]

Below is the console log
[image]

After this, the execution doesn't proceed and gets stuck there

Comment: Refer https://github.com/appium-userland/appium-flutter-driver/issues/181#issuecomment-1270213825 and https://github.com/appium-userland/appium-flutter-driver/issues/181#issuecomment-1323684510

Comment: if that works you can add [element listener](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/qaf_listeners.html) to add `flutter:setFrameSync` before and after command